# Parameter uncertainties for scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I fit a nonlinear function with several parameters using scipy.optimize.minimize to minimize the least-squares error. How do I find the variance of the parameters? I tried using the diagonal of the inverse of the Hessian, but the values are 100 times larger than the expected variances. I saw in [this question on Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93316/parameter-uncertainty-after-non-linear-least-squares-estimation) that the person rescaled the covariance matrix using the "number of measurements" but I don't know what that means.

I realise this question is basically a duplicate of [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593592/errors-to-fit-parameters-of-scipy-optimize), but that answer is not sufficient for me. In particular, the first answer says that the scipy.optimize.least_squares function returns the error on the parameters, which is untrue. The second answer does not address the case of least-squares minimization.

Comment: If you do not indicate why the answers from the previous post are not enough, the question is duplicated.

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited the question to explain why the other answers are not enough

Comment: Why do not you tell the author of the answer to his error?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry if this is a stupid question but how do I do that without commenting on his answer? I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: There is no other way, get more reputation, I think that 50 points are required to comment, SO offers different ways to obtain reputation: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)